# mysqli cant set encoding

Tags: mysql, mysqli, sphinx, sphinxql

i've been trying to set encoding for mysql connection to utf8

```
    $conn = mysqli_init();
    $conn->real_connect("127.0.0.1", null, null, null, 9306, null);

    $conn->set_charset('utf8');
    var_dump($conn->get_charset());die
```

but it's still latin1;

i need to use only mysqli because now i'm using SphinxQL query builder https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the problem [here](https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/pull/44)
problem was in mb_ encoding functions

Answer (score -1):

Try to set

```
sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
```

in your *source* section of *sphinx.conf*